# The QuickStart Guide documentation mongoDB code returns null

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, node-modules, atlas

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
// Replace the uri string with your connection string.
const uri = "<your URI string>";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);
async function run() {
  try {
    const database = client.db('sample_mflix');
    const movies = database.collection('movies');
    // Query for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future'
    const query = { title: 'Back to the Future' };
    const movie = await movies.findOne(query);
    console.log(movie);
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

This is the code from mongoDB quickStart Documentation I did all the steps correctly and also did everything right did put the correct uri string too but it returns null for the query , which is not according to the mongoDB quickStart Guide

Comment: Did you insert any data beforehand?

Comment: according mongoDB it was an  existing db and collection with the data here see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/connect-to-mongodb/

Comment: No,  it does not. The query and result data are just (fake) samples.

Comment: ohh now i see now thanks alot for real means alot I've stuck on this for a while now

Comment: From that docs page you linked, emphasis added: "_If you encounter an error **or see no output**, check whether you specified the proper connection string in the index.js file, **and that you loaded the sample data**._" If you follow some links around you can find [this page about loading the sample data](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/sample-data/#std-label-sample-data)